# Javascript Regexp : if a letter is adjacent to a number, add an underscore

Tags: javascript, regex, space

I need to check if the number is next to a letter, and if so, add an underscore.

For example:

```
Grapes23 --> Grapes_23
```

I've tried for quite a while, but I'm new to regular expressions. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
str=str.replace(/([A-z]+)([0-9])/i, '_'); //if number next to letter, add underscore
```

I'd appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: First of all, `[A-z]` will not match what you want it to, `[a-zA-Z]` will. Second, you are not using the capture groups you set up, you are replacing everything. Third, the `+` character means one _or more_ but in your case that wouldn't matter, so remove it. Also, the `\d` special character will match all digits and can take the place of `[0-9]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for a letter followed by a number:

```
str = str.replace(/([a-z])(?=[0-9])/ig, '$1_');
```

http://regexr.com?31qsr

How this regular expression works:

- `([a-z])` is any lowercase letter, wrapping it in parens makes it a
  "matching group"
- `(?=[0-9])` is a "lookahead". it basically means "followed by [0-9] (any digit)"
- `i` means ignore case (otherwise we would have to use `[a-zA-Z]`)
- `g` means global, or replace every match it finds (default only replaces the first one)
- `$1` means "first matching group", or the letter that was matched by the first bullet above.

Comment: I like this, and understand it, but since @gray said he's new to regex some explanation would help. (e.g. you're capturing the letter but not the number - how the heck does that work?)

Comment: in @jbabey's regex, you are not matching the number, simply a letter that is immediately followed by a number. this is why you don't have to re-insert the number in the replacement string.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly. I kindof understand what's going on, but I would have to study it to know exactly. And a thank you for everyone elses answers, really appreciate your help

Comment: @gray i'll add a brief explanation to my answer for posterity

Answer (score 4):

Run `str.replace(/([a-zA-Z])(\d)/g,'$1_$2')` on your string. This will look for any letter followed by a number, capture both the letter and number (note the parentheses) and then replace them with an underscore between the two. $1 and $2 are callbacks to the captured letter and number found in the regular expression match.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest approach is:

```
string.replace(/(\D​​​​​​​​​​​​)(\d)/,'$1_$2')
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Gy3A5/).

Note that this will only replace the *first* instance, if you wish to replace *all* instances, then I'd suggest the above, but with the `g` (global) flag:

```
string.replace(/(\D​​​​​​​​​​​​)(\d)/g,'$1_$2')
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Gy3A5/1/).

Comment: I wouldn't use `\D` as equivalent to the described "letter", since it will match any non-digit.

Comment: Ah, thanks, @Joe; I thought I'd missed an edge-case (my JS Fiddling was limited). =)